# MySQL Replication - How to avoid hard coding MASTER_PASSWORD when achieving Replication setup via automated script?

Tags: mysql, replication

In many other places, I am achieving it via following command:

```
mysql --defaults-group-suffix=xxxx -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%version%';
```

The actual password is in my.cnf.d/my_custom.cnf but how do I achieve something similar for setting up MASTER command (below):

```
mysql --defaults-group-suffix=xxxx -Bse "STOP SLAVE;CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='$MASTER_IP',MASTER_PASSWORD='HARD_CODED_PASSWORD',MASTER_USER='replicator', MASTER_LOG_FILE='$MASTER_LOG_FILE',MASTER_LOG_POS=$MASTER_LOG_POS;START SLAVE;"
```

Comment: You can query `mysql.user` and use of the following decryption listed [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html).

Comment: @alvits, i believe password is stored as hash. How can I use encryption/decryption functions here? If you can provide a little more detail here?